# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[] in ajaxtoolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I am getting these type of error.. please help me .. i having whole project completed. i dont know what to do next. Please please please help guys.

> ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll!ajaxcontroltoolkit.scriptcontrolbase.system.web.us.ipostbackdatahandler.loadpostdata(String
>   postdatakey,system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection
>   postcollection) Line426 +0*11 byets
>
> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467262   Message=Unable to cast object
>   of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[]'.
>   Source=AjaxControlTool`enter code here`kit   StackTrace:
>          at AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer.LoadClientState(String clientState) in
>   f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\Tabs\TabContainer.cs:line
>   567
>          at AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptControlBase.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) in
>   f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptControlBase.cs:line
>   315
>          at AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) in
>   f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\Tabs\TabContainer.cs:line
>   808
>          at AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptControlBase.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) in
>   f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptControlBase.cs:line
>   426
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the stack trace is:

> **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[]**

This means you are trying to convert a `String` to an array of `Object`, which of course makes no sense.

For more information on this exception [please refer to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference of Prototype.JS from page, this should resolve the error.

Comment: What reference are you talking about? There is no mention of `Prototype.JS` in his posted question...?